# How do I add Jquery VS intellisense reference to my view in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, javascript-intellisense

I am trying to get Jquery intellisense working in Visual Studio 2010.

I've looked around on StackOverflow and tried adding this to my view:

```
@{
     /// <reference path="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js"/>
 }
```

That's not working.. I've got it working by adding the same script tag to each view but this is less than ideal since i want to keep all my scripts in one place at the bottom of my layout page.

Comment: Are you using the JQuery library that came with MVC3 or are you using an updated JQ version?

Comment: Its version 1.5.1 that came with MVC3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `<script>` tags to each view inside an `@if (false) { ... }` block.

The IDE will still see them, and provide IntelliSense, but they won't do anything at runtime.

Comment: seems kind of like a hack but it works. I was almost certain that I read somewhere of a better way to do this using a comment block.

Comment: In order for VS to distinguish between the JQUERY and Razor syntax, it needs to have the script tags, as it natively thinks it is editing a .cshtml file.   As an alternative, you can create a javascript file .js for any jquery functions you want to write, and then include the .js file in the .cshmtl page.   There are some quirkies with this method though, as you will need to pass any dynamic razor data from the .cshtml page into the .js functions (as the .js file won't be able to evaluate @Model.whatever)

Comment: @David: VS is not making a mistake.  It is editing a CSHTML file.

Comment: @SLaks : That is correct, I was simply explaining why you have to have the script tags, even though you commented it seems like a hack.

Comment: @SLaks - Are you sure this works? I am trying this and it is decidedly not working. `@if (false)
{<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/PanelGenerator.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>}
` This script holds a js factory. `var pg = new PanelGenerator();` When I do `pg.` the regular intellisense comes up, but nothing about  the methods available from `PanelGenerator`. In addition, I have included the `/// <reference...` in the .js file. (win7 vs2010)

Comment: I realized my mistake. This does work. However, the razor engine sees `if(false)` and then does not compile `@Url.Content()` so I had to hardcode `src="/Scripts/PanelGenerator.js"` and now the IntelliSense works just fine.

Comment: @TravisJ: VS IntelliSense never parses `@Url.Content()` calls, even outside of `if` blocks.  (except maybe in VS11)

Comment: Is there some way to extend the Intellisense functionality so you can tell it to reference these files without these hacks per-file?

Comment: @ChrisMoschini: VS2012 supports a global _references.js